# Отправка формы (Formik) на сервер (json-server)

Tags: reactjs, requests, promise, formik

Пытаюсь отправить форму созданную в Formik на json-server но получаю предупреждение мол я использую не функцию а ожидается функция. и отправка не происходи. ни как не пойму что именно делаю не так.

```
const HeroesAddForm = () => {
    const request = useHttp()
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const onSubmitForm = (values) => {

        const newHero = {id: uuidv4(), ...values}

        request(`http://localhost:3001/heroes`, 'POST', JSON.stringify(newHero))
            .then(res => console.log(res, 'Отправка успешна'))
            .then((res) => dispatch(heroCreate(res)))
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }

    return (
        <Formik
            initialValues = {{
                name: '',
                description: '',
                element: ''
            }}
            onSubmit = {(values) => onSubmitForm(values)}>

            <Form className="border p-4 shadow-lg rounded">
                <div className="mb-3">
                    <MyTextInput
                        label="Имя нового героя"
                        required
                        type="text"
                        name="name"
                        className="form-control"
                        id="name"
                        placeholder="Как меня зовут?"/>
                </div>

                <div className="mb-3">
                    <label htmlFor="description" className="form-label fs-4">Описание</label>
                    <Field
                        as="textarea"
                        required
                        name="description"
                        className="form-control"
                        id="description"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Что я умею?"
                        style={{"height": '130px'}}/>
                </div>

                <div className="mb-3">
                    <label htmlFor="element" className="form-label">Выбрать элемент героя</label>
                    <Field
                        required
                        className="form-select"
                        id="element"
                        name="element"
                        as="select">

                        <option >Я владею элементом...</option>
                        <option value="fire">Огонь</option>
                        <option value="water">Вода</option>
                        <option value="wind">Ветер</option>
                        <option value="earth">Земля</option>
                    </Field>
                </div>

                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Создать</button>
            </Form>
        </Formik>
    )
}
```

[image: Предупреждение]

useHttp:

```
import { useCallback } from "react";

export const useHttp = () => {

    const request = useCallback(async (url, method = 'GET', body = null, headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}) => {

        try {
            const response = await fetch(url, {method, body, headers});

            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(`Could not fetch ${url}, status: ${response.status}`);
            }

            const data = await response.json();

            return data;
        } catch(e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }, []);

    return {request}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы неверно вызываете, у вас в request сейчас объект, сделайте:

```
const { request } = useHttp()
```

Comment: на сколько глупая ошибка, аж прям стыдно. Спасибо)

Comment: Бывает) Используйте typescript и таких ошибок не будет)